# Query to Find double byte character record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I have a table which contains double byte character records in the `FORMAT` column. I want to find which record contains double byte character? Is there any query to find the double byte character records?

I used the below query to find the records, but it returns both single and double byte character records in the `format` column.

```
select * from Product_Details
where language='JP' and convert(nvarchar(max),convert(varchar(max),FORMAT)) = FORMAT
```

-- Create Product_Details which has NVARchar column format

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Details
 (Language varchar(2), format NVarchar(max))
GO
```

--Populate Product_Details with single byte and 
--double byte in Format column

```
INSERT INTO Product_Details (Language, format) 
VALUES ('EN', 'Basavaraj')
 
INSERT INTO Product_Details (Language, format) 
VALUES ('JP', N'尊敬卿')
 
INSERT INTO Product_Details (Language, format) 
VALUES ('EN', 'Biradar')

Insert into product_details(Language,format)
   values('CN','你好')
```

Now i want to list records which format column contains double byte character data(for example Japanese language,Chinese language records..).The table contains lot of Chinese and Japanese language records.so i am trying to find out
which format column contains this records.

Required Output

```
Language         Format
 JP               尊敬卿
 CN               你好
```

GO

Comment: sample data and expected output would help

Comment: now i updated my question with DDL command and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to compare your column to it's converted non-Unicode counterpart. Those which do not match wouldn't be single byte.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e34467bb204c3d947515e0599514da0)

```
select *
from Product_Details
where [format] != cast([format] as varchar(max))
```

Comment: Happy to help @Ram

Answer (score 0):

If your FORMAT column is **n**varchar(max) then all values there will be double byted.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Product_Details
where datalength([format]) > 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately `DATALENGTH` won't work  here. Even if you changed it >= 2. [See the example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43881273a0758706f28566017aab5258). Also, code only answers tend to get down-voted since they lack explanation so be sure to explain your code :)